# How to call a file through Python scripting on cygwin

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I have written a python script which calls a .exe file and run it.

```
import subprocess
path = "C:\Tools\file.exe"
subprocess.Popen(path)
```

When I execute my Python file on windows, it run successfully but when I try to run the same script on Cygwin, it does not execute.

Can some one help me telling what is command on cygwin to run a file??

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, please edit your post to include the full traceback. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Under Cygwin you find the C:\ Drive under /cygdrive/c. You should try something like this:

```
import subprocess
path = "/cygdrive/c/Tools/file.exe"
subprocess.Popen(path)
```

Comment: Thanks Holger!!  It worked but now I am in another situation. I want to copy a file from my local machine to remote machine(logged in using telnet) using PSCP.exe But to my bad, when I use the same command, it does not let me push the file to remote machine when tried in Cygwin but works fine in windows again.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't even know what PSCP is. Maybe, you should open another question for that and mark this one as solved.

Comment: Np holger!!! I made it work. There was some time delay problem so increased the time.sleep value and it worked. Thanks for your input..